# Display JSON data using handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I need to figure out how to print the full JSON response onto my page (or even parts of it), but I can't seem to figure it out.  I am going to eventually fill out the page with more context later.

JS file:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
var context

apiLib.fetch('acct:chars', function(err, result){
    if(err) throw err

    context = result;
    console.log(result); 
    res.render('/', context);

    });

});
```

Handlebars:

```
 {{#each context.characters}}
 {{this.name}} 
 {{/each}}
```

JSON Data:

```
{
  "result": {
    '1234':{               //this is the character ID
      "characters": {
        "name": 'Daniel',
        "CharacterID": '1234'
        etc...
    }
   }
 }
```

My page prints nothing, but console logs everything.  I am using express.js to handle the routing.

Comment: Remove `this` in `this.name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is the `each` helper, here: `{{#each context.characters}}`. What `each` does is look *within the current context* for the variable. You've already passed Handlebars the `context` object when you called `res.render('/', context)`. So now Handlebars is looking *within* the `context` object for an attribute called `context`, and it won't find it. So you should change that line of code to `{{#each characters}}`.

The same thing applies to where you wrote `{{this.name}}`. I think that will actually work if you fix the other problem, but the `this` is unnecessary, because Handlebars looks at `this` (the current context) automatically. So just `{{name}}` should be fine there.

Finally, if you're really trying to just display the JSON file as a page of plain text, you don't need to run it through a Handlebars template. You can just use `res.json(context)`. This will return a JSON response. If your server is configured to handle the `application/json` MIME type, it should render as plain text in the browser.

Comment: thank you.  this worked!  I will be building out the page with more content, I just wanted to get that out of the way first.

Comment: @shelum happy to help! also, you might want to edit your question to clarify that you weren't trying to render it as plain text, to help future readers.don't worry about adding thank you answers or comments either: an upvote or selected answer is thanks enough! Check out some of the docs: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Answer (score 15):

If you want to display the stringified JSON, you can use an helper

**JS**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('toJSON', function(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 3);
});
```

**HTML**
    `<pre>{{toJSON result}}</pre>`

Answer (score 3):

Since you are iterating over objects in handlebars, it should be done as -

```
  {{#each context.characters}}
      {{#each this}}
         {{@key}} - {{this}}
      {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
```

Comment: I just tried that and now the page doesn't even load black and I get a "failed to lookup view '[object Object]' in the views directory" error when lloading the page

Comment: what does `context` contains .. ?

Comment: context contains the JSON data.  It is viewable in the console.

Comment: can you paste it ..? or is it the same as in the question .. ?

Comment: my server must've had a hiccup.  page is loading now but there still isn't anything printed to the page.  This is what shows up in the console: http://i.imgur.com/VhLTDri.jpg

Comment: the json in the image you provided is the context value ??

Answer (score 2):

If you are using it with Node.js and mongoDB this answer is for you;

Let's say you have the following response from your database called `data`:

```
{                                
  _id: "5AAAAAAAAAe04fc1a1", //some id idk
  BUSINESS: 'FLEX TAPE',          
  SHOWMAN: 'PHIL SWIFT',            
  CONTACT: 'PHIL SWIFT',         
  PHONE: '11111111113',       
  ETC: 'yes',                          
}
```

What you might want to look for to display the fields is to take advantage from client-side rendering. piping the `data` with the classic `JSON.stringify(data)` as `okData` for instance.. then you can just reference it using the `{{}}` notation.

e:g.

```
<p id="some-id" style="display: none"> {{okData}} </p>

<script>
let jsonStrLookup = document.getElementById('some-id').innerHTML
let js = JSON.parse(jsonStrLookup)

console.log(js)
</script>
```

This would work for SIMPLE applications hope it helps out, and if something seems off comment, I always check on here, and will try to help you.