# How to get the data back from mongoDB and display it properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

After I get the data from mongoDB how can I display it.

FOR EXAMPLE I have a simple hbs template

```
//index.hbs
{{# each user}}                 
         <div >
            <h5>{{ user.firstName }}</h5>
         </div>
         <div >
            <h5>{{ user.lastName }}</h5>
         </div>     
{{/each}}
```

now I can get the records from mongoDB with find.()

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect("connection string");
var userSchema = new Schema({
  "firstName":  String,
  "lastName": String,
  "locationID": Number
});

var User = mongoose.model("Users", userSchema);

User.find({ locationID: 1}).exec().then((data)=>{
console.log(data);
});
```

Also, how can I get all the data from the mongoDB. Not using the find(). to search the condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display JSON data using handlebars.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039555/display-json-data-using-handlebars-js)

Answer (score 0):

This is cleaner code for retrieving all documents in a given collection. You should be able to test this in Postman to verify it gives you the results you need--that's why I included the res.status().json() at the end.

```
const getUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
    

    const users = await User.find().exec();
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      results: doc.length,

      data: {
        data: users,
      },
    });
  };
```

Also just a note: Don't use var because it is bad practice. It causes scoping problems, clutters the global namespace, and is a source of errors. Use let or const. Also, when doing asynchronous operations, use async await because it makes the code a lot more readable.